# Unable to create folder in Android

Tags: java, android

I'm facing with this problem a couple days and I can't figure it out. So, I have an app that want to create a folder in root of internal directory (not in app internal directory, but in device internal directory) so I saw it is in fact external directory. Now I'm using code like that:

`File file = new File(getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), 'someFolder);
boolean created = file.mkdir();`

and on some devices this doesn't work. `created` are always false. I don't know on what devices, because I know that from Crashlytics (I can only say that on Samsung and Lenovo devices). On My Nexus 7 and Xperia Sola it works perfect.

Can someone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

replace your `file.mkdir()` with `(file.mkdir() || file.isDirectory())`.

Your call `getExternalStorageDirectory` needs to be `getExternalStorageDirectory()`
and check the state of external storage first, using [`getExternalStorageState()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getStorageState(java.io.File)) (== `Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED`) and log the return status of that; Do not try to create a directory on read-only or unavailable storage media.

Comment: sorry my mistake - it should be `getExternalStorageDirectory()` - I edited my post.
Yeah, but how it can be read-only if you have other folders there? like DCIM where you have your photos, Download - where you have your downloaded files? Many apps have their own folder in this internal device folder (for exaample, on Nexus 7 it's /emulated/0/).

Comment: did you check same dir already exists ? [mkdir can return false in that case](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#mkdir()).

Comment: Yes, `getExternalStorageDirectory()` dir exists. It also happens on emulator - `mkdir()` or `mkdirs()` returns `false`.

Comment: sorry i meant your `somedir`, please check for it using `file.isDirectory()` first. please see my update.

Comment: Yes, I can but it is not nice solution. My app also creates a cache to prevent multiple downloading the same images from server. Would you like to have 100+ files on your internal storage without any folder? Or maybe there is a way to get the Download or DCIM folder?

Comment: your dir will be there, we are just checking if it already exists or `mkdir` will create it; I agree you do not want to save 100+ files without a dir. `created` will be true from `file.isDirectory()` if your `somedir` exists.

Comment: You mean in device internal directory? The point is that `mkdir` returns `false` and folder is not created.

Comment: `mkdir` will return false if the directory you are trying to create already exists. This can happen if someone ran your app already or uninstalled, reinstalled. The same directory may already exist, in which case mkdir() will return false. Use `|| file.isDirectory()` as shown in my answer to get `true` when dir already exists.

Comment: on emulator it still doesn't work. I did something like this:`File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "wallpaper/");
        Log.d("f exists", Boolean.toString(f.exists()));
        Log.d("f mkdir", Boolean.toString(f.mkdir()));
        Log.d("f mkdirs", Boolean.toString(f.mkdirs()));
        File f2 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "wallpaper/");
        Log.d("f2 exists", Boolean.toString(f2.exists()));`. And all Logs printed false

Comment: on emulator you may not have allocated sd card. What does `getExternalStorageState()` say on emulator.